# Regex not returning as expected

Tags: regex

Why does `/[^A-Z][^0-9][^a-z]/` not match "#"? I am trying to match any character that is not an uppercase letter, number, or lowercase letter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You were very close. What you want is...

```
/[^a-zA-Z0-9]/
```

Answer (score 1):

```
/[^A-Z0-9a-z]/
```

is one of the ways to do the match you want

Answer (score 1):

`/[^A-Z][^0-9][^a-z]/` specifies a match of three consecutive characters (the first as anything but A-Z, the second as anything but 0-9, etc.), which is why it won't match a single character alone.

By consolidating these character groups into one (e.g. /`[^0-9A-z]/`), you are specifying a single character to match.

Answer (score 0):

Your regex requires 3 characters to match.  It would match, for example:

```
aA9
###
```

Etc.  Each set of square brackets represents a single character (via a character class).

As other answers also diagnosed, you probably wanted to use:

```
/[^A-Za-z0-9]/
```